# Problems deleting then inserting into SQL Server with READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

We are using SQL Server 2017. We have `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON`. We have a query that does a delete and then an insert like this:

```
begin transaction
SELECT DISTINCT STAGING.MyTable.CategoryId
INTO #categories_to_delete
FROM STAGING.MyTable;
commit;

begin transaction;
SELECT DISTINCT STAGING.MyTable.ItemId
INTO #items_to_delete
FROM STAGING.MyTable;
commit;

begin transaction;
DELETE FROM PROD.MyTableProd
FROM PROD.MyTableProd
INNER JOIN #categories_to_delete
ON #categories_to_delete.CategoryId = PROD.MyTableProd.CategoryId;
commit;

begin transaction;
DELETE FROM PROD.MyTableProd
FROM PROD.MyTableProd
INNER JOIN #items_to_delete
ON #items_to_delete.ItemId= PROD.MyTableProd.ItemId;
commit;

begin transaction;
INSERT INTO PROD.MyTableProd
SELECT
    CategoryId
    , ItemId
    , <other_columns>
FROM
STAGING.MyTable;
commit;
```

The primary key on both `PROD.MyTableProd` and `STAGING.MyTable` is `ItemId`. The prod table has about 12 million rows while the staging table gets truncated when data gets inserted in a previous step.

When this runs, we will frequently get primary key violations on the `insert`. My suspicion is that because of `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON`, the `insert` and the `delete` locks are not blocking each other, so the `insert` happens when the `delete` hasn't finished? However, I thought wrapping everything in transactions would prevent any issues like this? Any suggestions for preventing these primary key issues without having to turn `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` off? Is there a way to have it off for just this table?

Comment: The very fact that you use DISTINCT to generate a list of items to delete suggests that your table has duplicate ItemID values. Perhaps just rarely. To verify this, check for duplicate ItemId values in the staging table at the beginning of your script and throw an error.

Comment: It does not considering both tables have the same primary key columns.

Answer (score 1):

it's a database setting, you can't do it by table, but....

If you only have RCSI set to ON, it just changes read committed operations into snapshot reads. Updates, Inserts and Deletes are handled using normal transactional isolation.

> Setting the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON option allows access to
>   versioned rows under the default READ COMMITTED isolation level.

[Snapshot Isolation in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server)

In any case you should't see a PK violation due to snapshot isolation, though you can see update conflicts if there are two, concurrent updates/inserts/deletes on the same rows.

Comment: In doing some more testing, after the delete happens, when I do a select, I see rows still in the table that should have been deleted. I have to run the delete a few times before all the rows are gone. Could it be that the delete gets parallelized and so there's some weird concurrency thing going on with that?

Comment: If the delete hasn't been committed, you can still see them with read uncommitted.  OTOH if they are in another session and you're reading with snapshot isolation in a separate session, that's how RCSI is supposed to work. What you're suggesting would be an extremely-serious bug in the database engine, if true.

Answer (score 0):

> When this runs, we will frequently get primary key violations on the insert. My suspicion
>   is that because of READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON, the insert and the delete locks are not >blocking each other, so the insert happens when the delete hasn't finished?

You are using a different transaction for every command, if you want the delete to happen after the insert put them in the same transaction, e.g.

begin transaction
SELECT DISTINCT STAGING.MyTable.CategoryId
INTO #categories_to_delete
FROM STAGING.MyTable;

DELETE FROM PROD.MyTableProd
FROM PROD.MyTableProd
INNER JOIN #categories_to_delete
ON #categories_to_delete.CategoryId = PROD.MyTableProd.CategoryId;
commit;

begin transaction;
SELECT DISTINCT STAGING.MyTable.ItemId
INTO #items_to_delete
FROM STAGING.MyTable;

DELETE FROM PROD.MyTableProd
FROM PROD.MyTableProd
INNER JOIN #items_to_delete
ON #items_to_delete.ItemId= PROD.MyTableProd.ItemId;
commit;

With READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON the transactions do not block each other since all transactions read a snapshot of the table when the initial transaction started.